# Объясните фрагмент кода

Tags: javascript, классы, extend, конструктор

Создайте новый класс ExtendedClock, который будет наследоваться от Clock и добавьте параметр precision – количество миллисекунд между «тиками». Установите значение в 1000 (1 секунда) по умолчанию.

Не могу понять,что это за конструкция в строке (*)?

```js
lass ExtendedClock extends Clock {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    let { precision=1000 } = options;  // (*)
    this.precision = precision;
  }

  start() {
    this.render();
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.render(), this.precision);
  }
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. Это означает, что если в `options` не будет ключа `precision`, то по дефолту он будет 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таким способом можно задать значение по-умолчанию.

`let { variable=значение-по-умолчанию } = объект-со-свойствами`.

```
let options = { precision: 10};
let { precision=1000 } = options;
console.log(precision);
// 10


let options = { foo: "bar"};
let { precision=1000 } = options;
console.log(precision);
// 1000
```